# How to make a ring server reload on file change?

Tags: clojure, ring

How do you make a ring server reload during development whenever a file changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this dependency to your project.clj:

```clj
[ring/ring-devel "1.8.0"]
```

You can get the latest version number from [Clojars](https://clojars.org/ring/ring-devel).

Then require the following in the file where your request handler lives:

```clj
(:require [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]])
```

The wrap your handler:

```clj
(wrap-reload handler)
```

Example from a server using multiple wrappers:

```clj
(def handler
  (compojure/routes
    (GET "/" [] "hello world")
    (route/not-found "No such page.")))

(defn -main []
  (server/run-server
    (-> handler
      params/wrap-params
      wrap-reload)
    {:port 8080}))
```

You can find the documentation on the reload middleware [here](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.reload.html), and another example on how to use it [here](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Reloading).